# How diagnose ScriptBundle error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, bundling-and-minification

I am using the System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection class to bundle javascript files in an asp.net application.  The code looks like this:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
      public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
      {
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/mybundle").Include(
            "~/Content/js/mycustomfile.js",
            "~/Scripts/Select2.js"));
      }
}
```

And the bundle is consumed in an asp.net mvc view like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/mybundle")
```

I recently updated the "Select2" Nuget package to the latest version, and the updated version broke the "@Scripts.Render" call above with an "object reference not set to object" error.

When I reverted the Nuget update the problem disappeared.  This is obviously a problem with the Select2 version upgrade.

I would like to identify the line(s) of code in the Select2 javascript file that is causing the asp.net mvc bundler to break, so that I can notify the Select2 project authors.

Nothing in the error message or call stack indicates the problematic line(s) of javascript code.  Is there any way to discover **why** System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection is failing to include this javascript file in the bundle?

Comment: Does the file "~/Scripts/mybundle"  exist?

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC, no, I have no such file in my project.

Comment: The "object reference not set to object" error is probably just because the bundle is missing. The exception in the Bundler process would not show up on page load, but at bundle creation time.  You might find the real error in the log for whatever you are calling the Bundler with- are you using Task Runner?  Grunt?  I don't use Select2 but i looked at their code.  Last update was 3 months ago.  What version did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC I upgraded to their latest version. I'm using the built-in bundling and minification that comes with asp.net mvc. There is no log that I can find. There is no doubt what the issue is--the latest version of Select2 breaks bundling and minification.  My desire is to find the exact line(s) of javascript code that is/are causing the failure.  I don't know how to trap the error.

Comment: Hi Tom. It's helpful to look at the diff, which is why i also asked for the version from:  What version did you upgrade from and to?  I got the to: part.  What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.3.  When I updated to 4.0.7 it broke.  I did diff the two versions, but there were a lot of changes, nothing obvious leaped out at me.

Comment: without spending time to reproduce the bug myself, I would look at this commit first- https://github.com/select2/select2/commit/45a877345482956021161203ac789c25f40a7d5e